How to custom draw objects via GPU and others via EEVEE?
I'm currently writing a custom renderer for blender to draw objects via a GLSL shader and the GPU API to the viewport.
These objects have a lot of custom attributes, and the node-based materials are not sufficient as they require a lot of logic / are very dynamic.
This part however is now already working.
After trying a few variants, i noticed that they all come with drawbacks.
If i register a custom rendering engine (bpy.types.RenderEngine) i can render objects just fine, however regular materials without my attributes need special handling.
There seems to be no way to default back to e.g. EEVEE if i can't draw it myself.
Instead of a rendering engine, simply registering a draw handler also works (bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add) and allows me to ignore regular materials.
However i can't seem to get both EEEVEE to ignore these objects while still letting it render with my custom draw code.
It's either both or none, unless i have a dummy materials that does e.g. alpha clipping.
Is there any good way to get custom rendering for some objects, while letting others be drawn as usual?

Can you not just render in two passes? Get everything you can in your engine in one pass then just switch to a pass with just the EEVEE objects, switch engines and render. Then combine in the compositor. It'd probably be pretty easy to automate.

It's part of a tool used for editing meshes, so it will never be rendered.
So it should be drawn to the viewport

Ah I see, thought it was a custom render engine like for rendering as EEVEE or Cycles would.
